# TFS Reports from web site

Tags: tfs, tfs-web-access, tfs-reports

I'm having trouble getting the TFS reports to show any data when I use the web portal.  When I run the TFS reports thru the Visual Studio the reports show up correctly, but when I go to my TFS web portal I get the option for the report, but when I run it I get a blank report, no error message, just a blank report.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

That web site (on the right hand side) doesn't belong to Team Foundation Web Access. It's SQL Server Reporting site.

What happens, if you try to open that report on a different browser?